# Why does calling a named assigned function fail in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, anonymous-function

The following is probably a bit senseless, but why does the first call below work while the second one fails?

```
var foo = function bar() {
  console.log("Martini");
}

foo(); // works
bar(); // undefined; i.e. "Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined"
```

Has that to do with scope?

Corollary beginner's question: The function definition "parses" - but is that actually valid syntax - and is there any context where naming an assigned anonymous function makes sense?

Comment: I think I found the answer to the second part of my question here: [In Javascript, when is it necessary to assign a named function to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627048/in-javascript-when-is-it-necessary-to-assign-a-named-function-to-a-variable)

Comment: Must read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/338053/652669

Comment: Another important difference between function declarations / expressions is, that the former are hoisted with their name and function body, while the latter are only hoisted with their name, that is, `foo` is `undefined` until its function body is reached in the code.

Answer (score 8):

Function *declarations* create a variable with the same name as them in the current scope.

Function *expressions* (named or anonymous) do not. The name of a function expression is available as a variable *inside* the function (where it is useful for calling itself recursively) and in debugging tools.