# Anonymous function name behaves differently between browsers?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I was doing some exercises in a book and I've came accross this example:

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var canFly = function() { return true;}
        
        window.onload = function() {
          console.log('Assert: "' + window.canFly.name+'"');
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However upon executing in Chrome 51 and Firefox 46.0.1, I've realized they behave a bit different.

Namely, Chrome seems to return `Assert: "canFly"` while Firefox returns  `Assert: ""`. According to the book, Firefox behavior is the expected one.

My questions is either of these two behaviors the 'correct' one, in reference to the spec?

Comment: What book? When was it written?

Comment: Secrets of a JavaScript Ninja, 2013.

Comment: In ES6, the function name is inferred from the assignment target.

Comment: Anonymous function generally doesn't have `name` property until you name them `var x = function x() { }` (see the second x). Looks like Chrome is always ahead and detect correct name in this situation to help you debug program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read a book about a web technology that is constantly changing, expect that some or all of the information will be out-of-date.

In ES5 there was no `name` property defined for [function instances](https://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5), nor was it defined for [`Function.prototype`](https://es5.github.io/#x15.3.3.1).

---

In ES2015, the `name` property was defined for [function instances](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-name):

> The value of the name property is an String that is descriptive of the function. The name has no semantic significance but is typically a variable or property name that is used to refer to the function at its point of definition in ECMAScript code. This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true }.
>
> Anonymous functions objects that do not have a contextual name associated with them by this specification do not have a name own property but inherit the name property of %FunctionPrototype%.

it was also defined for [`function.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object):

> The value of the name property of the Function prototype object is the empty String.

There's also an algorithm defined called [`SetFunctionName`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname), which appears to handle assigning a `name` property in a variety of cases, such as when a function is used as part of an object literal.

---

This is as far down the rabbit hole as I've dug. I would not be surprised if Chrome and Firefox had different levels of support for the `SetFunctionName` or if there were differences between the ES2015 and ES2017 specs that would lead to the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 4):

- The ES5 spec says nothing about `.name` properties of functions, therefore it should be `undefined`.
- (Some) browsers still implemented function names as a feature, and anonymous functions would have no name, therefore it should be `""`. Additionally, developer tools would be more clever, and name some anonymous functions for debugging purposes (but not give them a `.name` property).
- The ES6 spec gives anonymous function expressions that are assigned to variables a `.name` property, so it should be `"canFly"`.

Now choose yourself which of those you consider "correct" :-) Your book might be a bit outdated, and FF is a bit behind at implementing this new ES6 feature.

Comment: [Here's a spec link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-name), I'm digging into where the `Function.prototype.name` property is defined.

Comment: [Here's the prototype spec link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object), looks like anonymous functions should have a `name` of `""` per the spec.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33629506/1048572) and [many other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bes6%5D+anonymous+function+.name) where it's mentioned

Answer (score 3):

I think here’s your answer: [Function "name" property (ES6)](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5135002249461760).

Basically, it’s the “smarts” of Chrome’s DevTools, and a behavior apparently supported by newer JS standard.

Answer (score 0):

> Variables and methods can infer the name of an anonymous function from
>   its syntactic position (new in ECMAScript 2015).

```
var f = function() {};
var object = {
  someMethod: function() {}
};

console.log(f.name); // "f"
console.log(object.someMethod.name); // "someMethod"
```

It might be helpful to read about [inferred function names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).